# Visual Studio: any one click switch between tabs and spaces indentation?

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style, indentation

I'm member of several different teams and (of course ;) some teams prefers tabs over spaces and vice versa.

Is there any more user friendly solution then loading user profile via menu->Tools... which is 10 clicks long?

I looked at devenv.exe command line parameters if there is any for loading particular user profile to have two separate *.lnk launchers of Visual Studio, but there isn't such parameter.

Then I tried to record macro, but VS is able to record only the Tools.ImportandExportSettings command and cannot record all the steps of the following wizard.

Thx for suggestions,
Petr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `InsTabsOff` and `InsTabsOn` commands from [Productivity Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/dbcb8670-889e-4a54-a226-a48a15e4cace) extension.

Comment: `InsTabsOff` and `InsTabsOn` are in Quick Launch Tasks in Productivity Power Tools 2017

Answer (score 5):

There is a macro in this [blog entry](http://www.jamesralexander.com/blog/content/visual-studio-toggle-between-leading-tabs-or-spaces-project) by James Alexander to quickly toggle between tabs and spaces within Visual Studio.  Then just add a toolbar command that maps to the macro and you have your one click solution.

```vb
Public Sub ToggleTabs()
  If DTE.ActiveDocument.Language = "CSharp" Then
      Dim currentSetting As Boolean = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "CSharp").Item("InsertTabs").Value
      DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "CSharp").Item("InsertTabs").Value = Not currentSetting
  End If

  If DTE.ActiveDocument.Language = "SQL" Then
      Dim currentSQLSetting As Boolean = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "SQL").Item("InsertTabs").Value
      DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "SQL").Item("InsertTabs").Value = Not currentSQLSetting
  End If

  If DTE.ActiveDocument.Language = "HTML" Then
      Dim currentHTMLSetting As Boolean = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "HTML").Item("InsertTabs").Value
      DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "HTML").Item("InsertTabs").Value = Not currentHTMLSetting
  End If

  If DTE.ActiveDocument.Language = "JScript" Then
      Dim currentJScriptSetting As Boolean = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "JScript").Item("InsertTabs").Value
      DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "JScript").Item("InsertTabs").Value = Not currentJScriptSetting
  End If

End Sub
```