# In Visual Studio 2010 is there a way to toggle the tab and indent size quickly, without having to navigate the options each time?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I do WinForms and Web development in Visual Studio 2010.  The web developers use a tab size of four spaces, and the WinForms developers use a tab size of two.

Since I switch backwards and forwards between the two, I was wondering if there's a quick way to do it, without having to navigate the options every single time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not a dedicated shortcut, but let's make one!

Simply hit `Alt+F11` to bring up the Macros editor and add the following code to a new module:

```
Imports System
Imports EnvDTE
Imports EnvDTE80
Imports EnvDTE90
Imports EnvDTE90a
Imports EnvDTE100
Imports System.Diagnostics

Public Module Tabspaces
    Sub TwoTabSpaces()
        Dim tabs As Properties

        tabs = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "AllLanguages")
        tabs.Item("TabSize").Value = 2
        tabs.Item("IndentSize").Value = 2

    End Sub

    Sub FourTabSpaces()
        Dim tabs As Properties

        tabs = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "AllLanguages")
        tabs.Item("TabSize").Value = 4
        tabs.Item("IndentSize").Value = 4

    End Sub

End Module
```

Then save your macros and bring up the *Options* window from the *Tools* menu and choose *Environment->Keyboard*:

[image: assigning macros]

Here, you can search for commands containing '*macros*' and you should see your `TwoTabSpaces()` and `FourTabSpaces()` listed.
You can now assign a keyboard shortcut to these macros. In the picture above, I've chosen `Alt+T, Alt+2` and `Alt+T, Alt+4` respectively (t=Tabs, 2=two spaces etc.)

You can customize them as you wish, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd share my personal macro that does a toggle based on language. You can set up keyboard shortcuts like suggested in Widor's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10800879/945456).

```
Public Sub ToggleSpaces()
  If DTE.ActiveDocument.Language = "Basic" Then
    Dim textEditorSettings = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "Basic")

    Dim currentSize = CShort(textEditorSettings.Item("TabSize").Value)

    'If at 2, use 4... else switch to 2
    Dim newSpaces As Short = If(currentSize = 2, 4, 2)    

    textEditorSettings.Item("TabSize").Value = newSpaces
    textEditorSettings.Item("IndentSize").Value = newSpaces
  End If
End Sub
```

My macro was adapted from James Alexander's macro to "[Toggle Between Leading Tabs or Spaces Per Project](http://www.jamesralexander.com/blog/content/visual-studio-toggle-between-leading-tabs-or-spaces-project)" found in the following StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298909/visual-studio-any-one-click-switch-between-tabs-and-spaces-indentation).